# Having problems understanding celery

Tags: python, django, celery

This is my first time learning celery and django. I have installed the latest version of celery (`celery==3.1.17`) and rabbitmq (`amqp==1.4.6`) inside my virtualenv. I'm learning from [celery's website](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html).

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Count(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.x
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = CountForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.cleaned_data:
                count = form.save()
                count.x = add.delay(count.x)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
        all_counts = Count.objects.all()
        form = CountForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html',{
        'form':form,
        'all_counts':all_counts
        })
```

template:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="post">
    </form>
    {% if all_counts.count > 0 %}
        {% for count in all_counts %}
            <p>ID {{count.id}} =  :: Value = {{count.x}}</p>
            <br/>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No counts</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

**Update**

tasks.py:

```
@app.task
def add(x):
    while x <= 50:
        return x + 1
        time.sleep(3)
```

What I want to perform through celery is to add the x of Count till it is equal to 50, so that the each calculation and result value will be stored asynchronously. *Therefore, after each 3 seconds I should see the value of count.x changing asynchronously till the value is 50*. But in the template i'm getting the same value what I posted. What am I missing? Will you please help me to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't celery for async tasks?

Comment: @Alvaro Yes.. I am missing something... I think I should change the views to be non blocking so that the calculation and result value  will be asynchronous. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not that fluent with celery, but you should check the various messaging backends that can be used to keep track of the state of the task. Check this: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results

Comment: I don't believe add is going to do what you want it to do.  It will return immediately after hitting the return statement.

Comment: @user2097159 Ok. Can you please show me how to achieve it then.

Comment: You are definitely misunderstanding celery. Celery is meant as a *task queue*. It will not magically update any template.

Comment: @barraponto Yes. I meant that it will change the value of count.x every three seconds. Have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Celery is not meant for this**.

What you are trying to do might be achieved with pure js or even with an ajax django view.

You can use a timer in js to make async calls to the server and ask the current value, every 3 seconds. Then, you should update the html accordingly, using js or even JQuery.

Check out [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). It's pretty convenient for working with async calls to the server.

**What Celery is for**

Celery is for heavy background tasks that can be performed either by a different machine or async, so that the request doesn't time out on high processing time or the resources are better managed. It won't do anything related to your template rendering, as its mostly a task queue utility.

Comment: I don't think DRF will help though. OP just wants a simple view which responds with a single value: DRF is massively overkill for that.

Comment: Sure, but I'm guessing this is just a silly example.. I wouldn't even use ajax for a counter

Comment: @Alvaro I don't want celery to perform a realtime app kindish that would asynchronously call the server. I just want celery to perform calculation on the background, so that after each 3 seconds if will increment the value of `count.x`, and if I refresh the page I should see change in the value, till the value is 50. I hope I was clear now.

Comment: Oh, I see. Update the question with the user refresh aspect. I'll check the docs and update the answer

Comment: @Alvaro Ok. great! Will be waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `add.delay` starts an asynchronous task in the worker, and immediately returns [`AsyncResult`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html)object. If you want to access the actual return value of the task, you need to call `AsyncResult.get()`. This will block until the task is completed in the worker.

```
return_value = add.delay(count.x).get()
```

More details in the [documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html).

Comment: ok. I am sure I am missing something? How do I do the calculation and store the value asynchronously without blocking ?